# ¿Qué significa la expresión "a consideración"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, sinónimos

Estaba escribiendo un ensayo que debía ser en tercera persona. Y en vez de poner "en mi opinión" puse "A consideración del autor de este texto". Luego pensé en si el significado de la expresión era equivalente. ¿Lo es? o ¿qué significa la expresión "a consideración"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me temo que con el contexto que estas ofreciendo decir "**en mi opinión**" y "**a consideración**" no son equivalentes... tal vez lo que estas buscando es "**la consideración** aunque esto termina siendo muy ambiguo.

Cuando dices "**En mi opinión**" se puede decir que estas ofreciendo tus "**consideraciones**".

Sin embargo "**A consideración**" no significa eso. "**A consideración**" quiere decir "**en atención a**" o "**tomando en cuenta a**", "**teniendo presente a**".

Y esta es utilizada para marcar como una idea o suceso esta sujetada otras condiciones.

Por ejemplo:

> "En consideración a su gran esfuerzo se le otorga el reconocimiento a..."

Mi recomendación es que simplemente transformes tus opiniones en opiniones generales y prepositivas e hipotéticas.

Como:

> "Se puede opinar", "Es posible"

por ejemplo:

> En mi opinión esto no es correcto
>
> > Es posible que esto no sea correcto
> >     Se puede opinar que esto no es correcto

Pero si utilizáramos:

"en consideración al autor de este texto esto no es correcto" no indica una opinión, indica que por alguna razón la presencia del autor transformó el resultado; o sea, no es una opinión, es un hecho.

Pero también se puede reparar si transformamos el "en" a un "la"

> "La consideración del autor de este texto es que esto no es correcto"

*voilà*! , esto si es una opinión.

Answer (score 1):

"A consideración" se usa así en México, pero no encontré esta frase con el uso que le diste ni en Collins, DRAE o linguee.com.  Pero no somos tú y yo nomás.  Encontré este uso en https://pt.slideshare.net/anaidvelazquez/avances-tecnolgicos-7264489?ref=&smtNoRedir=1:

> La GTI a consideración del autor no es más que un conjunto de operaciones....

[image: from slide show]

Es mucho más común

**someter a consideración**

Aunque todavía no lo encontré en los diccionarios, hay muchos ejemplos en [linguee.com](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/someter+a+consideraci%C3%B3n.html):

> Señor Presidente, desearía someter a consideración del Pleno algunas observaciones....